# "Namely" vs. "specifically"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

> We need more information about this guy. **Specifically** / **Namely**, what is his name, where he lives, and whether he has a gun.

It is assumed that we don't need any other facts. We don't care whether he has a big and very angry dog, a drive license, and whether he sleep with the knife under the pillow.

Which word should be used in such a case, "specifically" or "namely"?

Comment: It feels casual, with a note of urgency, as if a chief inspector of police is giving orders to their small team. *We need more (information) about/on this guy: his name, (his) location, whether/if he has a gun.* You could leave it out altogether... Otherwise, any of namely/particularly/specifically should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having "namely" and "his name" so close is not a bright solution. I would avoid repetition:

> We need more information about this guy. *Specifically*, (we need to know) his name, his address, and whether he has a gun.

Note: There are many synonyms of ***[namely](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB888GB888&sxsrf=ALeKk01gD1QZyyjPqGFRhxWJoy-k9E758A%3A1609155719144&ei=h8TpX-CqCOXlxgOhzarIDw&q=namely%20synonym&oq=namelysynonym&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yCAgAEAcQChAeMggIABAHEAoQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIECAAQCjoECAAQR1DoT1iOV2CuaGgAcAN4AIAB2QGIAe4EkgEFNC4xLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab)*** that you can use in this sentence. ***Specifically*** may sound a bit too formal for the register you are using. To keep the same register you could say:

> We need more information about this guy, ***and I mean*** his name, his address, and whether he has a gun.

Comment: Thanks. So, "namely" and "specifically" have the same meaning in sentences like this, and the only difference is the tone?

Comment: They are synonyms in this instance, and yes, "specifically" is slightly more formal than "namely"

Comment: The reason ***namely*** is "incorrect" in the cited context isn't to do with the fact that the noun ***name*** occurs in close proximity. It's because ***namely*** should be followed by ***the specific name of something / someone*** (which / who has previously been "obliquely / implicitly" referenced by earlier text). It doesn't really make sense to follow ***namely*** by *[**specific**] example questions*.

Comment: I found this example on [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/namely.html) : "The prison setting ultimately serves as a backdrop to the deeper question posed by the film, namely, can a claymation skit hold water." But I think I understand how your point is different from my example.

Comment: @fev: Great example of "namely" usage! In that sentence, and all proper uses of "namely", the earlier part, "the deeper question posed by the film", describes obliquely what is made plain in the second part, "can a claymation skit hold water".